# i want to run Background Service in a Web Application using timer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, scheduled-tasks

hi i want to run a background service (schedular) in my web application. Throught the service i want to execute a query when date is changed.
So could you please tell me that at which event i write the code in application.
currently i am using

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if (DateTime.Now.ToString() == "14-02-2017 11:55:08")
        {
            b4_production_report_excel obj = new b4_production_report_excel();
            int a = obj.insert_comment("2017", "1", "TAB", "Comment", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see this pop up a bit and the general answer is that it shouldn't be done, but there a few libraries that exist and seem to do an okay job of it. There are a few mentioned here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Please don't. Offload this work to a separate process like a WebJob when running on Azure or a Windows Service or Scheduled Task when running on a Windows Machine. Web applications are not meant for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is no big problem. But you had to make the Timer1 run automatically.

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
        </Triggers>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if (DateTime.Now.ToString() == "14-02-2017 11:55:08")
        {
            b4_production_report_excel obj = new b4_production_report_excel();
            int a = obj.insert_comment("2017", "1", "TAB", "Comment", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

You can also look the following link supported by Microsoft
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb398865(v=vs.100).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Comment: i want to run this not on a page but for hole application to update some data in DB, so where i write the code that when the date is changed then  this can call automatically

Comment: As the post code above,  the Timer1_Tick method will be automatically called by the page every 1 second,  you can freely use the Timer1_Tick to implement your application(update data to DB or something else) .  Lastly, all you need to do is to write some code in the Timer1_Tick method. Did I make you clear?